# How can I save to a json file the timer values and read them back?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using EditorWindow.

At the top of the script:

```
private int h = 0, m = 0, s = 0;
private static int Hours = 0;
private static int Minutes = 0;
private static int Seconds = 0;
```

Inside OnGUI:

```
private void OnGUI()
{
  EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
        Hours = EditorGUILayout.IntSlider("Set the hours",Hours,0, 59);
        Minutes = EditorGUILayout.IntSlider("Set the minutes", Minutes, 0, 59);
        Seconds = EditorGUILayout.IntSlider("Set the seconds", Seconds, 0, 59);
        if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())
        {
            h = Hours;
            m = Minutes;
            s = Seconds;
        }
}
```

And the saving method:

```
private void SaveTimerValues()
    {
        string jsonTimer = JsonHelper.ToJson(, true);
        File.WriteAllText(@"d:\json\json.txt", jsonTimer);
    }
```

The class JsonHelper:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;

public class JsonHelper
{
    public static T[] FromJson<T>(string json)
    {
        Wrapper<T> wrapper = UnityEngine.JsonUtility.FromJson<Wrapper<T>>(json);
        return wrapper.Items;
    }

    public static string ToJson<T>(T[] array, bool prettyPrint)
    {
        Wrapper<T> wrapper = new Wrapper<T>();
        wrapper.Items = array;
        return UnityEngine.JsonUtility.ToJson(wrapper, prettyPrint);
    }

    [Serializable]
    private class Wrapper<T>
    {
        public T[] Items;
    }
}
```

Inside the SaveTimerValues the sonHelper.ToJson should get the first parameter as array.

And loading back the values:

```
string jsonTimer = File.ReadAllText(@"d:\json\json.txt");
        if (jsonTimer == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
```

But how do I first save the timer values and then how do I read them back and assign them to each variable: Hours Minutes Seconds ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to save and read values like this. Think about making class **Timer**

```
class Timer {
    public int Hours = 0;
    public int Minutes = 0;
    public int Seconds = 0;
}
```

But you should really Consider using `DateTime` and use this instead.

Also `JSON` is just simple string, so you can save it using

```
string timerInJson = UnityEngine.JsonUtility.ToJson(timer);
File.WriteAllText(@"d:\json\json.txt", timerInJson);
```

And read it like that.

```
string jsonTimer = File.ReadAllText(@"d:\json\json.txt");
Timer timer = JsonUtility.FromJson<Timer>(jsonTimer);
```

Comment: You need the Serializable attribute on the Timer class.